# Getting error from Parse while debugging Google login

Tags: parse-platform, oauth, google-plus, acl

So I'm trying to integrate Google login with Parse using the "Bring your own login" system. I was able to get the basic authorization functionality to work using the code snippets at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/UUvTreGYOrI.

Now, to do some testing, I went ahead and manually deleted the user object via the Parse dashboard. However, I am now getting the following error when trying to access go through the signup workflow:

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: {"code":101,"message":"object not found for get"}
```

I tried clearing the cache and uninstalling the app, but the issue persists. Can anyone help me how to get around this and start the registration process afresh?

On a more fundamental note, this is my first time implementing code OAuth, logins, and ACLs. As such, any resource/tutorial that can give me code examples of this integration with Parse on both the CloudCode and the client (app) side would be highly appreciated (I believe the current official Parse tutorial uses Git and only has samples of the server side CloudCode).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I figured it out.

I had to delete the entry in the TokenStorage class on the Parse dashboard. I guess that's storing the token that links the login with the User object.

Anyway - I'm keeping this open to see if someone can point me to a good sample code for this workflow.